# Significato di "trasmettere le proprie emozioni"

Tags: meaning

Buongiorno,

Ho dubbi sul significato di "trasmettere le proprie emozioni". Non riesco a capire se questo costrutto significa fare sì che un altro capisca come ci sentiamo, o se significa fare sì che l'altra persona provi la stessa cosa che proviamo noi, e magari anche che reagisca da quel momento in poi nello stesso modo da un punto di vista emotivo qualora presentarogli quella stessa situazione che ha fatto sì che noi stessi ci sentissimo così.

Grazie per i chiarimenti.

Comment: “presentarogli”? Intendi “gli si presenti”?

Comment: Quanto alla domanda, io che sono un madrelingua italiano non saprei come intendere un'espressione di quel tipo. Se qualcuno la usasse con me, gli risponderei “parla come magni!” (espressione romana per esortare qualcuno ad esprimersi in termini semplici e schietti).

Comment: Semplificando: significa dire come ci sentiamo, cosa proviamo, sperando che l’altra persona capisca.